# How do I copy structures using pointers to structures?

Tags: pointers, structure, copying

I need to copy one instance of a structure to another, using the respective structure pointers. The code I have tried is as follows:

```
typedef struct{
int a, b, c;} test;

int main(){
test *q, *w;
(*w).a = 2;
(*w).b = 3;
(*w).c = 4;

printf("\n%d\n%d\n%d", (*w).a, (*w).b, (*w).c);

memcpy((void*)q, (void*)w, sizeof(test));

printf("\n%d\n%d\n%d", (*q).a, (*q).b, (*q).c);

return 0;
```

The output I get is:

```
2
3
4
1875984
32768
1296528
```

Can someone please tell me how to copy the structure? I need to use pointers to structures, simply doing:

```
test w, q;
q = w;
```

will not suffice for my program.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the line in your code:

```
memcpy((void*)q, (void*)w, sizeof(test));
```

with the following line:

```
memcpy((void*)&q, (void*)&w, sizeof(test));
```

Comment: I tried this. The program displays a runtime error - it doesn't run to completion. Thanks for answering though - any other ideas?